# How to check if a range specified by iterators is valid?

Tags: c++, iterator, std

Many of the standard library containers have operations that accept a range specified by iterators. For example, `std::list::assign(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)`.

But because many of these operations do not throw exceptions, if the range specified by `[first,last)` is not valid, it will cause undefined behaviour.

So what *is* a valid range? I assume it means that `first` comes before or is equal to `last` in the container, because when I tried otherwise (i.e. `first` comes after `last`), the program's execution would hang.

For example:

```
std::list.assign(container.begin(), container.end()); // valid range
std::list.assign(container.end(), container.begin()); // invalid range
```

Now with an assumption of what a valid range is, how can we check if a range is valid?

I came up with a helper function that checks if `first` is ever equal to `last` before it reaches the end of the container. If true, it's a strong guarantee that `first` does not come after `last` and therefore the range is valid.

```
template <typename Iterator>
bool isValidRange(Iterator first, Iterator last, Iterator end)
{
  for (; first != end; ++first)
    if (first == last) return true;
  return false;
}
```

It's not very convenient because you have to pass it an iterator to the end of the container in addition to the iterators that specify the range.

Is this correct? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: To check whether a range is valid, increment the first iterator until it is equal to the second; then you know it's valid. If it never equals the second, then the range is not valid.

Comment: On a more serious note: don't equate ranges and containers. Containers are one way of creating ranges, but they are not the only way. For example, an iterator into an input stream does not come from a container.

Comment: @PeteBecker In that case, why does something like `list_a.assign(list_b.end(), list_b.begin());` hang the program? `std::list::end` and `std::list::begin` return a bidirectional iterator, so the first iterator will eventually reach the second, meaning it should be valid according to your description.

Comment: You can't get from `list_b.end()` to `list_b.begin()` by incrementing. You have to decrement, because `end()` comes after `begin()`. Having a bidirectional iterator means that you can decrement it as well as increment it, unlike a forward iterator, which doesn't support decrementing. That doesn't change the nature of a range; ranges run from the first iterator to the second, regardless of the category of the iterator.

Comment: @PeteBecker I'm not sure I understand. If I have an iterator that points to the past-the-end element using `end()` and I increment it once, my code tells me that it is now equal to `begin()`. Also, `std::iterator::distance(l.end(), l.begin())` tells me the distance is 1 no matter the size of the container, because it's only one increment away. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I should have put a smiley in my earlier comment about incrementing until you reach the end; that's not a practical test, because incrementing a past-the-end iterator produces undefined behavior, so the "test" is only valid when you have a valid range to begin with. I had in mind Will Rogers' comment that the way to make money in the stock market is to buy a good stock and when its price goes up, sell it; if it doesn't go up, don't buy it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> how can we check if a range is valid?

You can't. Your function cannot guarantee that the range is valid, only that the last is reachable from the first. These are two different things (for a simple example, consider an iterator into a vector which was subsequently reallocated). There is no mechanism by Standard that permits you to check if a range is valid. Much like you cannot know that a pointer is valid before you de-reference it.

Just to note, Microsoft provided a function to check if a pointer was valid and it utterly screwed everyone who used it. Raymond Chen said that it should have been named CorruptMemoryIfPossible.

Comment: I found the post by Raymond Chen: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/09/27/773741.aspx. Good read. TL;DR you should just crash when given invalid input.

Answer (score 1):

`[iterator.requirements.general]` defines the "valid range" term:

> 10 A sentinel s is called reachable from an iterator i if and only if there is a finite sequence of applications of the expression ++i that makes i == s. If s is reachable from i, [i, s) denotes a valid range.

So "last is reachable from the first" is exactly equal to "valid range" definition from the standard PoV (and hence for UB definition). Dereferencability of iterators is orthogonal to this definition.